# Ensure data integrity in relational DB?

Tags: mysql, database-design, referential-integrity, data-integrity

Let's imagine I want to store in a relational database the following :

- A list of quizzes
- A list of questions associated with quizzes
- A list of users
- The answers to questions made from users.

I could have a model like this:

[image: proposed data model]

However, this doesn't ensure any integrity in the following cases:

- A question has been modified so the corresponding answer is now wrong
- New questions are added to an existing quiz, so the score students will be different

With MySQL I don't know any way to prevent this kind of data corruption unless to put the database in read-only mode. The only alternative I can think of is to use a `revision` column for both the `quizzes` and the `questions`. Then to use a composite primary key that identifies a question from its `revision` and its `id`.

My current idea is to have a JSON column in the `activities` table that freeze the state of a quiz at a certain moment in time. Then the hash of this activity can be stored somewhere in a blockchain.

What would be the alternatives?

Comment: Two observations 1: get rid of the row pointers (`Ids`) from your data model until you have everything laid out and know when they are appropriate.  You won't have any integrity as long as they are thrown into your model so haphazardly. 2. The proper design pattern to follow is to use only stored procedures to make changes to the data, you can incorporate logic to disallow edits to quizzes once they have been made available/taken.

Comment: I'll submit an answer later when I have enough time to build out examples/diagrams.

Comment: If your base data change may affect on dependent data correctness then your scheme is wrong. You must have 2 similar table structures. First stores quiz-questions-answers parttern which is currently actual - the scheme block "parrents". Second stores quiz-user-questions-answers entities which represents the state of the pattern for the time point when the user acts and user's answers/results - the scheme block "results". These 2 scheme blocks have no any relation between them.

Comment: @Akina this is a good idea, but then how to ensure the integrity of the second pattern? If the database is corrupted, how can you detect it?

Comment: Seems to me like this is a job for triggers. Whenever a question gets updated, the AFTER UPDATE trigger on that table automatically updates the answers to flag them as no longer accepted - or needing review. That or the trigger rejects the update (raises an exception) if you want to block changes to questions with an accepted answer ?

Comment: Same when a new question is added to a quiz. The AFTER INSERT trigger can automatically adjust the scores. Note that you also need to think about question deletions. Should they be allowed ? What is the impact on existing answers and student scores ? Should a question be deleted for good ? Or retained but marked as « removed by the author? ». The latter means that existing answers can be retained too (even if no longer used for scoring). Otherwise they need deleting too. This can be done via the trigger, or automatically via the foreign key constraint CASCADE option).